# Markers aren't displaying

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, marker

This is my code where i have parsed json array. I'm getting correct values in my logs but to that parsed value markers are not displaying on map. Please check my code and tell me where i am going wrong.?

Here is my code,

```
public class NearActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap gMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_near);
        gMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {

            new HttpGetTask().execute();

            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 14));

            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                    .getLongitude())).title("I'm here"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.near, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        Double lat = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)
                .getLatitude();
        Double lng = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)
                .getLongitude();

        String URL = "http://latlong.in/api/stores/36/around_me.json?app_id=test&lat="
                + lat + "&lng=" + lng;

        AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            try {

                return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {

                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                    Log.v("Response", result);

                    JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String point = e.getString("point");
                    Log.v("POINT", point);

                    String[] point2 = point.split(",");
                    double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(point2[0]);
                    double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(point2[1]);

                    Log.v("LLDN", "" + lat1 + "&" + lng1);

                    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(
                            e.getString("name")).position(
                            new LatLng(lat1, lng1)));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (null != mClient)
                mClient.close();

        }
    }
```

This is my json response

```
[
{
point: "77.606706,12.967060",
distance: "1.41",
id: 5686,
ph: "1234",
name: "zxcvb",
LS: " asdfrewrtet"
},
{
point: "77.606706,12.967060",
distance: "1.41",
id: 5686,
ph: "1234",
name: "zxcvb",
LS: " asdfrewrtet"
},
{
point: "77.606706,12.967060",
distance: "1.41",
id: 5686,
ph: "1234",
name: "zxcvb",
LS: " asdfrewrtet"
},
]
```

Comment: does it raise any exception?

Comment: thanks fellas... I found that..
it was just lat lng miss place..